# SciChart dynamic annotations

Tags: c#, wpf, scichart

In the SciChart tutorials there are only instructions how to add a `LabelProvider` with hardcoded `Label` texts, that can be switched on different values (https://www.scichart.com/example/wpf-chart-example-stacked-column-side-by-side/). Is there any way to programmaticaly add and handle axis labels?

UPD: Idea is to mark columns with different labels, so that every column has a text label instead of numeric value on the main axis.

Comment: What do you want to handle? Can you give more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is pretty obvious. To dynamically handle labels from `ViewModel`, you can bind a `LabelProvider` itself.